# JQuery Active toggle/add/remove class issue

Tags: jquery

I have an app where you can choose any combination of 6 divs as selected or not (marked by class `active`), then a 7th div which when selected clears all the others.  I have the jquery working except for the addition of the `active` class to the 7th div.  Here's a fiddle:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.q4-answer').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('#q4-all').on('click', function() {
       $('#q4-all').addClass('active');
       $('.q4-answer').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  border: solid thick white;
  text-align: center;
}

.answer img {
  width: 30px;
}

.answer.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid thick black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="q4-legs" class="answer q4-answer">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
  <p>Legs</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-chest" class="answer q4-answer">
  <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
  <p>Chest</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-back" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Back</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-biceps" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Biceps</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-triceps" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Triceps</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-shoulders" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Shoulders</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-all" class="answer q4-answer">
    <img alt="A full body workout. Huzzah!" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d3/11/eb/d311eb7f9e927ea7ba604387f6278558.jpg" />
     <p>Full Body</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone figure out why that last problematic div isn't getting the `active` class when clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click 7th div (Full body dog), you are adding first a class 'Active' to him and then removing all classes, so it removes his class too. You simply need to change order. This should work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.q4-answer').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('#q4-all').on('click', function() {           
       $('.q4-answer').removeClass('active');
       $('#q4-all').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap lines `$('#q4-all').addClass('active');` and 
`$('.q4-answer').removeClass('active');` around

You are adding it with the first and then removing it with the second. Here you want to remove it and then add it.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer indicate - swapping the order of the lines corrects the problem. I also added logic to remove the class from the "full body" option so that it cannot be selected at the same time as any of hte other options. Same with the selection of full body - individual options are deselected if you have selected full body. Just to increase functionality :)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.q4-answer').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('#q4-all').removeClass('active');
    });
  
    $('#q4-all').on('click', function(){
       $('.q4-answer').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  border: solid thick white;
  text-align: center;
}

.answer img {
  width: 30px;
}

.answer.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid thick black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="q4-legs" class="answer q4-answer">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
  <p>Legs</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-chest" class="answer q4-answer">
  <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
  <p>Chest</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-back" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Back</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-biceps" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Biceps</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-triceps" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Triceps</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-shoulders" class="answer q4-answer">
   <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/256/cat-grumpy-icon.png" />
   <p>Shoulders</p>
</div>

<div id="q4-all" class="answer q4-answer">
    <img alt="A full body workout. Huzzah!" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d3/11/eb/d311eb7f9e927ea7ba604387f6278558.jpg" />
     <p>Full Body</p>
</div>
```